# Cannot upgrade chromedrive version & error: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I get the exception message in the console:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
        (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
      Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
      System info: host: 'PL30004702', ip: '192.168.1.237', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
      Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.33.506120
```

Actually the webdriver clicks and that step should be passed, but I get that exception.
I wrote about that in other forums and a few persons adviced that I should upgrade the chromedriver ***from 2.33 to 2.35*** and I downloaded that, however there is still 2.33 written in the console.

What did I wrong? How I can handle this error and go further with developing the script?
My Chrome version is ***80.0.3987.149***